# Azure Linux webapp backup restore from storage container fail PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

N:B
Manual restore from Portal working well and Powershell restore is not working

I am going to use PowerShell via AzureDevops pipeline jobs to do the restoration.

Azure app hosted in Austalia East
Web app backup goes to Australia Southeast where the Azure storage account is configured.
Web app name mywebapp

I have configured Azure Linux web app backup to the Azure storage account container. I am trying to restore the backup to webapp.

Here are the steps that I used.

Deleted original web app in Australia East (mywebapp)
Created a new web app in the Australia Southeast region with similar configurations.

I am trying to restore using PowerShell (backups are in Azure storage account)

Here is the command I used

```
Restore-AzWebAppBackup -BlobName 'myapp_202109230658.zip' -Name 'myapplive' -Overwrite -ResourceGroupName 'myapp_migrated_env' -StorageAccountUrl 'https://amyappstorage.blob.core.windows.net/appbackup?sp=r&st=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0:20:03Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%3D' -debug
```

I used generated SAS URL of the storage container to  StorageAccountUrl

This is the error I am getting

```
    {
```

"Code": "BadRequest",
"Message": "Required parameter AccessKey is missing.",
"Target": null,
"Details": [
{
"Message": "Required parameter AccessKey is missing."
},
{
"Code": "BadRequest"
},
{
"ErrorEntity": {
"ExtendedCode": "01010",
"MessageTemplate": "Required parameter {0} is missing.",
"Parameters": [
"AccessKey"
],
"InnerErrors": [],
"Details": [],
"Code": "BadRequest",
"Message": "Required parameter AccessKey is missing."
}
}
],
"Innererror": null
}

Restore-AzWebAppBackup: Long running operation failed with status 'BadRequest'.
DEBUG: AzureQoSEvent: Module: Az.Websites:2.8.2; CommandName: Restore-AzWebAppBackup; PSVersion: 7.1.4; IsSuccess: False; Duration: 00:03:56.0777035; Exception: Long running operation failed with status 'BadRequest'.;
DEBUG: Finish sending metric.
DEBUG: 2:24:56 AM - RestoreAzureWebAppBackup end processing.

Followed Azure documentation and not working restoring process.

Restore-AzWebAppBackup command does not support any accesskey parameters

```
Restore-AzWebAppBackup
   [-AppServicePlan <String>]
   [-Databases <DatabaseBackupSetting[]>]
   [-IgnoreConflictingHostNames]
   [-ResourceGroupName] <String>
   [-Name] <String>
   [[-Slot] <String>]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [-StorageAccountUrl] <String>
   [-BlobName] <String>
   [-Overwrite]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

So I need to fix the issue and restore the web app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have tested in our local environment , by creating  2 webapps in central us  location with same configurations. we took  backup from one of the web app & tried restoring the same configuration to other  web app using the below PowerShell cmdlet which  is working fine.

```
Restore-AzWebAppBackup -ResourceGroupName "<resourcegroupName>" -Name "<webNameNeedtobeRestoredto" -StorageAccountUrl "SAStokenurl_for_generatedBackup" -BlobName "<backupFileName>" -Overwrite
```

> "Code": "BadRequest", "Message": "Required parameter AccessKey is missing.", "Target": null, "Details": [ { "Message": "Required parameter AccessKey is missing." }, { "Code": "BadRequest" }, { "ErrorEntity": { "ExtendedCode": "01010", "MessageTemplate": "Required parameter {0} is missing.", "Parameters": [ "AccessKey" ], "InnerErrors": [], "Details": [], "Code": "BadRequest", "Message": "Required parameter AccessKey is missing." } } ], "Innererror": null }

Based on the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/restore-azwebappbackup?view=azps-6.4.0) ,`Restore-AzWebAppBackup` command doesn't have access key parameter in the cmdlet definition.

We would suggest you to open a discussion over [Microsoft Q&A](http://Microsoft%20Q&A%20supported%20products%20%7C%20Microsoft%20Docs) or raise a technical support ticker by following the [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket) where technical support team would help you in troubleshooting the issue from platform end.

Comment: Thank you for the check my issue.  My same region and cross-region restore worked in US regions. But I don't know why the same commands failed in AUS Regions. However, now I can restore the backup in different AUS regions using the same command.  It is so weird.

Comment: @dedosan - as per your comment i have tested the creating & restoring web app configuration in same Australia south east region and it is working fine for us . here is the screen shot for reference 
https://imgur.com/nzvhd5M

Comment: Glad I could help, can you please accept the answer as solution. This could help other community users who have similar query in the future